# How to configure chrome debugger to show only typescript files in the call stack window?

Tags: typescript, google-chrome, debugging, google-chrome-devtools

I know how to debug typescript project with chrome, but it will be much more efficient if the call stack window will show only the typescript files, and not the js files.

Is it possible? How?

In the following image I added red arrows pointing to the files that I need in the call stack.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can ignore the scripts one by one by right clicking on the stack trace and choosing "Add script to ignore list". It's a bit tedious, but there should only be a finite number of scripts to ignore.

Otherwise you could try writing a rule in "settings" > "ignore List". But when I added a rule to ignore all javascript files (".js$"), it broke my debugger and I couldn't step through typescript files either any more.

see also: [Is there a way to hide 3rd party JS function calls in stack trace in chrome or firebox debugger?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45991646/is-there-a-way-to-hide-3rd-party-js-function-calls-in-stack-trace-in-chrome-or-f)

Comment: It is not a full solution to but it really usefull. Thanks